# How do i catch system Logoff/ShutDown/Lock events in Python or PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have an application in .NET now i am recoding it using Python and PyQt. In my application i need to know system events (Lock,Logoff,Restart and Shutdown). I could able to manage it from .NET Frame work 3.5 using below snippit

```
AddHandler SystemEvents.SessionEnding, AddressOf ClosingApplication
AddHandler SystemEvents.SessionSwitch, AddressOf SessionSwitchEvent
```

Depending on the system i need to do some stuff to update my Database.

Can any one help me plz...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to use the [pywin32 library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/).  It is a wrapper class for the win32api.  You can then use the [SetConsoleCtrlHandler](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/pywin32/win32api__SetConsoleCtrlHandler_meth.html) to catch the signal.

To cleanly capture the signal you are going to need to spawn a console window. To make your application run cleanly, you can run the console window in a hidden state.  For more information about how to spawn the console window see: [Python - Windows Shutdown Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411186/python-windows-shutdown-events)

Comment: Its of no use, i tried the links that you gave. i don't see any result