# Python handling system shutdown

Tags: python, windows, events, multiprocessing, shutdown

I have a multiprocessed python application which is being run as an EXE on windows. Upon selecting to shutdown the operating system the applications throws a number of exceptions as a result of the processes being shutdown.

Is there a way to capture the system shutdown request by windows so I may handle the closure of the multiprocesses myself?

Comment: What exceptions does the application throw when “windows” shuts down?

Comment: It is throwing exceptions to do with pipes not being writable, and io errors. Basically the application is multiprocessed and I think each of the processes is getting the shutdown command at a different time so I need to handle the shutdown command so I can do some graceful termination.

Comment: checkout python's `subprocess` module

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Windows Shutdown Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411186/python-windows-shutdown-events)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [nabble.com](http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/Catching-Windows-Shutdown-events-td1950035.html) page suggests using `win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler`:

> “I need to do something when windows shuts down, as when someone presses the power button.  I believe this is a window message, WM_QUERYENDSESSION or WM_ENDSESSION.  I can't find any way to trap this in python.  atexit() does not work.  Using the signal module to trap SIGBREAK or SIGTERM does not work either.”
>   You might be able to use win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler and catch the CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT that's sent to the console.

Also see  [Python windows shutdown events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411186), which says, “When using win32api.setConsoleCtrlHandler() I'm able to receive shutdown/logoff/etc events from Windows, and cleanly shut down my app” etc.