# Python script to automatically log out of Gmail upon pc shutdown

Tags: python, gmail

I have an idea to write a script that can detect my pc's shutdown and automatically log out of my Gmail account (for security reasons).

So far I can only think of the following:
 + find a way to detect the logout event
 + find a way to link the script to my Gmail account
 + write a script to log out of Gmail

I would really appreciate if someone could give me a hint on how to approach this task!  (anything would help!)

Comment: If there is a method or code block you have tried before, can you share it please?

Comment: This describes how to catch windows's shutdown event: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914495/python-handling-system-shutdown

Comment: You can use selenium to open your browser and log out of your Gmail account.