# Python detect sleep mode in windows10

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I want to find out if I can launch a function or a method in a python program right before the computer sleep, something that goes along the line of

```
def f():
    if about_to_sleep:
        do_stuff
    else:
        do_some_other_stuff
```

that can work in windows 10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Windows Shutdown Events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411186/python-windows-shutdown-events)

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145516/detecting-computer-program-shutdown-in-python