# Python do something before system shutdown?

Tags: python

I have a question. I want to have a python program running constanlty in background that is sending some data over serial to microcontroller. What i want to do is to send a special message when my pc is turning off. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Is it enough to send a message when python is closed? Otherwise, we need OS info.

Comment: If you are on windows, the answer is probably here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411186/python-windows-shutdown-events and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145516/detecting-computer-program-shutdown-in-python

Comment: I dont understand most of what is happening in this links that u provided :( . I want to run it on Windows 10. Can you give me some example code please? and yes sending message is all i want to do.

Comment: No, I mean do you need to detect Computer shutdown, or is Program ending enough? The second one is really simple to do.

Comment: I need to detect computer shut down because my program is a loop that never ends

Comment: So does anyone have an idea? @MegaIng?