# Notify when user clicks on shutdown button

Tags: python, windows, kernel, hook, shutdown

Is there the possibilty that I can know with Python when a user clicks on shutdown / runs the *shutdown.exe* in Windows so I can safely terminate a program before the shutdown happens? And by terminating safely I mean storing current values of another application so the user doesn't lose them. I guess when the user runs the shutdown process a new process will get registrated in the kernel so I thought maybe I could see through the `SetWindowsHookEx` function if there is a new "shutdown-process"? Is this the only way? And I'm also not really sure, if this is even possible.

Comment: Proper way is WM_QUERYENDSESSION/WM_ENDSESSION in Win32.

Comment: I believe you want to do the same as this post?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411186/python-windows-shutdown-events