# How to create Python event that should invoke on before windows sleep mode

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need Python event that should log present time into a file when windows receive sleep request. Below is my main code,

```
import subprocess

# Here code required to log the time at which system going to sleep
command = 'Sleep.py'
# Some usefull stuff
if subprocess.call(command, shell=True):
    print 'Success'
else:
    print 'Fail'
```

Below is 'Sleep.py' code,

```
import os
os.system("Rundll32.exe Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Sleep")
```

Can any one please provide solution to this

Comment: AFAIK, there is no simple way to do this. You will need to listen for the WM_POWERBROADCAST message. you can see some kind of examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411186/python-windows-shutdown-events

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jacobr

Comment: @jacobr, can you please make your comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved to answer as requested by asker.

As far as I know, there is no simple way to do this. You will need to listen for the WM_POWERBROADCAST message. You can see an example of listening for the shutdown event here: [shutdown example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411186/python-windows-shutdown-events)

It should be similar except you are listening for  WM_POWERBROADCAST with PBT_APMSUSPEND.

You can read about WM_POWERBROADCAST [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373247(v=vs.85).aspx)

You can read about PBT_APMSUSPEND [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372721(v=vs.85).aspx)