# How to run a function before PC shuts down with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

Is it possible to run a function in Python before the PC shuts down? Or lets say while it is shutting down?

Maybe using os module, or something else.

So let's say I have this function and I want to run it while PC is shutting down:

```
def onShutDown():
    # lets say send an email
```

BTW: I know how to send an email with smtplib so that is not the problem here.

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411186/python-windows-shutdown-events

Answer (score 0):

Well you can run a code and then in the same code you can instruct the PC to shutdown.
You can use the os module and use this piece of code below.

```
os.system('shutdown -s')
```

Well if you will execute the above code it give you a message "You are about to be signed out in less than a minute".
If you wish not to see it , then use

```
os.system('shutdown -s -t 0')
```

Well be careful when you are trying any code of this sort just in case you don't mess up. .

Comment: I didn't ask how to shutdown my computer...